# From java on linux connecto to odbc on windows. Is it possible?

Tags: java, odbc

We are developing a java application that runs on a linux server, we need to integrate with an odbc connection on a windows box.

Is this possible?

Pablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use a product like [JDBC-ODBC Bridge](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc_odbc_bridge/index.html) from Easysoft.

BTW: I never used those, but I know this company also works (or worked?) on the [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) open source project.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC is Microsoft techology which provides a standard interface for databases, backed by drivers for the specific database you're connecting to. I think the question you need to ask is if the database you're using has JDBC support (which is almost certain).

Comment: Hi

the need to integrate with is a 4d database http://www.4d.com. Our database is a MySQL (an we are very happy with it).

Our app runs on linux / glassfish. or from it, we need to do some sql to this 4D server that runs on windows.

Comment: There is a really slow/limited jdbc driver for 4d but the odbc driver seems to offer a bit better performance. We were wondering if by setting up this odbc dns on the 4d server, we could connect to it from our java linux app.

Answer (score 0):

You can run an [RmiJdbc](http://rmijdbc.ow2.org/) (server) on the Windows box and then use the RmiJdbc client from the Linux box.